# Python logger is not printing debug messages, although it is set correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging, contextmanager

I have the following code, where I just want to play around with the `logging`
module using `contextmanager`.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import logging

@contextmanager
def log_level(level, name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    old_level = logger.getEffectiveLevel()
    print('log_level.old_level: ' + str(old_level))
    logger.setLevel(level)
    print('log_level.new_level: ' + str(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
    try:
        yield logger
    finally:
        logger.setLevel(old_level)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with log_level(logging.DEBUG, 'my-log') as logger:
        print('__main__.log_level.logger.level: ' + str(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
        logger.debug('Debug with logger: will print')
        logger.warning('Warning')
        print('__main__.log_level.logger.level: ' + str(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
    print('__main__.logger.level: ' + str(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
```

As one can see, inside the main.log_level, the logger level should be DEBUG and it should print the message 'Debug with logger: will print'. However, when I run the code, this debug message does not print. Looking the prints of the code, It says that the logger has DEBUG level while inside log_level, and that the level goes back to WARNING when it exits log_level. Here it is my output, when executing with python 3:

```
log_level.old_level: 30
log_level.new_level: 10
__main__.log_level.logger.level: 10
Warning
__main__.log_level.logger.level: 10
__main__.logger.level: 30
```

I would like some help to understand why `logger.debug('Debug with logger: will print')` is not printing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You haven't attached any handlers to your logger. As a result, an internal "handler of last resort" is used, which only outputs events at levels `WARNING` and above. See [this part](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#what-happens-if-no-configuration-is-provided) of the documentation to see what happens if no handler configuration is provided. If you call `logging.basicConfig()` before your `with` statement, the `DEBUG` messages should appear.

Note that the docs also contain [working example](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-a-context-manager-for-selective-logging)s of using context managers with logging.

Comment: Thank you Vinay, now it is working. I will read the documentation and the example you mentioned to understand better what is going on. Cheers.