# Python logger not showing DEBUG level messages even though handler level is set to debug

Tags: python-3.x, python-logging

I'm trying to create a logger that prints "debug" messages. I've defined handlers with the correct level set. Still it only prints warning levels and above.

This is my code:

```
import logging

# Create a custom logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Create handlers
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
f_handler = logging.FileHandler('file.log')
c_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Create formatters and add it to handlers
c_format = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)

# Add handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(c_handler)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)

logger.warning('This is a warning')
logger.error('This is an error')
logger.info('This is an info')
logger.debug('This is a debug')
```

While this is the console output I get:

```
__main__ - WARNING - This is a warning
__main__ - ERROR - This is an error

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've found [similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312978/python-logger-is-not-printing-debug-messages-although-it-is-set-correctly) about this problem, but in that case the handlers were not set. My handlers are set.

What's wrong here?

PS: Code is a slightly altered version of [this page](https://realpython.com/python-logging/), section "using handlers".

Comment: Your handlers are `DEBUG`-level, but the _logger_ is not (it's [level 0](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels) by default, `NOTSET`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting to set the `logger` level

```py
import logging

# Create a custom logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Create handlers
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
f_handler = logging.FileHandler('file.log')

# handler level is different from logger level
c_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# this will do the trick
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Create formatters and add it to handlers
c_format = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)

# Add handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(c_handler)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)

logger.warning('This is a warning')
logger.error('This is an error')
logger.info('This is an info')
logger.debug('This is a debug')
```

You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668633/what-is-the-point-of-setlevel-in-a-python-logging-handler)